# Problem with setCollideWorldBounds and overlap Phaser 3

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I have problem with Phaser 3.

When e setCollideWorldBounds it give me error "Cannot read property 'setCollideWorldBounds' of null" and the overlaping function doesn't work. And the most strange thing is that in my game config my debug option is true, but only in this sprite it's not visible.

game config

```
export const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  backgroundColor: "#125555",
  width: 1200,
  height: 900,
  scene: Battle,
  physics: {
    default: "arcade",
    arcade: {
      debug: true,
    },
  },
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Player.ts

```
 export class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
  constructor(scene: Phaser.Scene, texture: string) {
    super(scene, config.width / 2, config.height - 150, texture);
    scene.add.existing(this);
  }
....
```

My scene

```
export class Battle extends Phaser.Scene {
  private player: Player;
  private enemy1: Enemy;
  private enemy2: Enemy;
  private enemy3: Enemy;
  constructor() {
    super("playGame");
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.image("background", "assets/space.png");
    this.load.image("player", "assets/playerShip.png");
    this.load.image("bullet", "assets/laserBullet.png");
    this.load.image("enemy1", "assets/enemy1.png");
    this.load.image("enemy2", "assets/enemy2.png");
    this.load.image("enemy3", "assets/enemy3.png");
  }

  create() {
    this.player = new Player(this, "player");
    this.player.setScale(0.09);
    this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

    this.enemy1 = new Enemy(this, "enemy1");
    this.enemy2 = new Enemy(this, "enemy2");
    this.enemy3 = new Enemy(this, "enemy3");
    this.enemies = this.physics.add.group();
    this.enemies.add(this.enemy1);
    this.enemies.add(this.enemy2);
    this.enemies.add(this.enemy3);
    this.playerCollision = this.physics.add.overlap(
      this.player,
      this.enemies,
      this.hitPlayer,
      null,
      this
    );
  hitPlayer(player: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite, enemies) {
    this.resetEnemy(enemies);
  }

  resetEnemy(enemy) {
    enemy.y = 0;
    let randomX = Phaser.Math.Between(0, config.width);
    enemy.x = randomX;
  }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the player to the physics of the scene.
This should fix it.

```
 export class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
  constructor(scene: Phaser.Scene, texture: string) {
    super(scene, config.width / 2, config.height - 150, texture);
    scene.add.existing(this);
    scene.physics.add.existing(this);
  }
```